# Read status of contex.Result() in override method of OnActionExecuting

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-mvc-filters

I'm overriding OnActionExecuting method in order to perform some checks before calling some controllers' methods and I was wondering if there was any way to read context.Result() value to check if it's equal to - for example - Status 401 Unauthorized or similar, in order to perform different actions on different status, like this...

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context) {
    base.OnActionExecuting(context);
    if (/*context.Result()==401*/)
    {
        //do things
    }
    else
    {
        //do other things
    }
}
```

Is there any way to read `context.Result()` value/status in order to use it inside an if() statement?

Comment: First of all, `Result` is a property not method, second - did you tried and faced some problem?

Comment: @SeM yes, if i write the statement as `if(context.Result==UnauthorizedResult)` i get the following error: `'UnauthorizedResult' is a type, which is not valid in the given context`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get and compare with [`Response.StatusCode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpresponsebase.statuscode?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Web.HttpResponseBase.StatusCode);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5.1);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.7.2):

```
if(context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode == (int)System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
{
    //Rest of code goes here
}
```